# docker error "The Launch URL 'http://localhost:{ServicePort}' is invalid." on running in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, docker, .net-core

I have a project on Docker and Visual Studio but build on Docker is ok but on the running project, I receive an error:

> The Launch URL 'http://localhost:{ServicePort}' is invalid.

I checked the Docker process list and my build is on running state

> 1bbc43ced68e        kalgramweb:dev      "C:\remote_debugger\…"   3
>   minutes ago       Up 3 minutes        0.0.0.0:8972->80/tcp
>   cocky_mccarthy

but I cannot open the site in the browser with port 8972.

any suggestion?!

Comment: why the error message says "ServicePort" instead of actual port? Is it being launched from command line and it is not being replaced? Can you access on localhost:8972 on browser?

Comment: I don't know why says ServicePort I just push run button. No, I do not have access to localhost:8972.